# Clarification Question with MAX and COUNT (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a couple homework problems and am a little confused how to use COUNT and MAX in my queries. I was wondering if someone can explain to me the 'where' part of these, or if I am just writing my coded completely wrong:

The Catalog relation lists the prices charged for parts by Suppliers. Catalog.pid is a foreign key to Parts.pid. Catalog.sid is a foreign key to Suppliers.sid. Write the following queries in SQL. Execute them to make sure you get the correct answers. Copy the SQL queries and include the screenshot of the results as the answers. Do not list other attributes not specified in the return results.

Catalog contains: pid, sid, cost

Parts contains: pid, pname, color

Supplier constains: sid, sname, address

c. (2 points) Return the number of unique parts.

```
select count (distinct *) from Parts;
```

--This produces a compilation error on select, does anyone have advice for this?

i. (1 point) Find the pids, pnames, and the maximum cost for that part among all the suppliers.

```
select p.pid, p.pname, c.cost from Parts p 
  inner join Catalog c on c.sid = p.pid
  inner join Suppliers s on c.pid = s.sid
  where max(c.cost);
```

I am not entirely sure if I am starting this correctly and I dont know what to consider when doing the 'where' part.. is it always needed?

Comment: For counting unique number of parts, you are on the right track!

Comment: For maximum cost, use max(c.cost) in Select clause. No need to use where max(c.cost)
Instead of that, use `group by p.pid, p.pname`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya when I put what i have there is a compilation  error on select.. do you have any idea why that would be>

Comment: what is the final query and error ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya the query is the same as what is listed and the error is: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct *) from Parts' at line 1

Comment: also what is the point of group by?

Comment: Do `select count (distinct pid) from Parts`

Comment: `group by` is for second question, where you are trying to find maximum cost withing a grouping of a specific part (pid).

Grouping is done because a part (pid) will have multiple suppliers and prices etc. So you need to find the maximum value out of the group for a specific pid

Comment: "also what is the point of group by? " Well `GROUP BY <column>` makes unique `groups` of your column.  so if you have the values `1, 1, 2, 3` in your <column> your groups are `1, 2, 3`.. for example `GROUP BY gender` makes the groups `male`, `female`... Using `GROUP BY` in a query only makes sense when you are using aggregate functions  like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MIN` or `MAX` by the way.. The aggregate functions works on a group.. if you want to unduplicate there is a better option `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct pid) from parts.
```

In above distinct is unnecessary because most probably pid will be primary key for part. So, above result should be same as

```
select count(pid) from parts.
```

Second query should not need join with Supplier as it is across all suppliers.

```
select p.pid, p.name, max(c.cost)
from parts p left join catalog c
on p.pid=c.pid
group by 1, 2
```

Comment: @kade i would advice not to use `group by 1, 2` but use `group by p.pid, p.name` instead... `group by 1, 2` means grouping on the order of column in the select clause so 1 maps to `p.pid` and 2 maps to `p.name`.. What happens if you change the select clause into `select p.pid, max(c.cost), p.name` instead.. `group by 1, 2` is more error prone besides it's not ANSI SQL so most likely this only works on MySQL.

Comment: Agree. But just too used to writing short hand. :) I believe it works on postgres as well.

Comment: "But just too used to writing short hand" i don't really write short hand i even also not use table aliases to shorten the table name.. i use full quantified table names all the time in mine queries.. Main reason shorted aliases are used in the EXPLAIN output making the EXPLAIN output a bit harder to understand which record in EXPLAIN output matches your real tables/subqueries or delivered table because you need to backtrack from the EXPLAIN output to your query.

Answer (score 1):

for distinct part  id a part is identified  by an id

```
select count(distinct pid) from Parts;
```

or if the pid is an auto_increment you could the rows

```
select count(*) from Parts;
```

You should not use  an aggregation function in where condition  ..eg: `where max(c.cost)`  the where condition in evaluated  first  before the aggreagtion function are performed so the where clause can't know the value for max() 
 if you want filter for an aggregated  result you shoudl use having

eg     `having c.cost = max(c.cost)`   but in this case you cant use an aggregated function without group by for the non aggregated  columns in select and get another type of error .

but if you need  also aother columns you could use a subquery

```
    select p.pid, p.pname, c.cost 
    from Parts p 
    inner join Catalog c on c.sid = p.pid
    inner join Suppliers s on c.pid = s.sid
    inner join  (
        select max(cost) max_cost
        from Catalog
    ) t on t.max_cost = c.cost
```

Comment: When I do the solution for the first question I get the error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct pid) from Parts' at line 1

Comment: Any idea as to why? I am using MySQL 8.0